# Copying one full column of a CSV file and adding it to another file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a tsv file with 8 columns, need to cut and paste only 7th column into another txt file

in.tsv:

```
API    Admin1    Admin2    Admin3    Admin4    Admin5    Request    Response_Code
v1/customers    200    401    401    401    401    { "customer": { "name": "abc", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} }    200
```

i have tried below commands:

```
paste -d, in.tsv |  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{print $7}'

cat in.tsv | cut -d \, -f 7 > out.txt

awk -F"," '{print $7}' in.tsv > out.txt
```

with above commands I'm able to copy only the first row.

Output should be as same as in.tsv

out.txt:

```
{ "customer": { "name": "abc", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} }
```

Comment: Your input looks like tsv, not csv

Comment: @oguzismail: Perhaps the csv file was actually comma separated and not correct pasted here, or space-separated. You can't be sure it is `tsv`.

Comment: @satheesh : The error is not completely clear. I think you want to see the seventh column only but you get something else. What do you get?

Comment: File type will  be CSV not TSV, I have shared the input file replacing "comma" with "space", i want to copy only 7th column with full without escaping the char

Comment: API,Admin1 ,Admin2 ,Admin3 ,Admin4 ,Admin5 ,Request ,Response_Code,,
v1/customers,200,401,401,401,401,{ "customer": { "name": "abc", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} },200
v1/customers,200,401,401,401,401,{ "customer": { "name": "def", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} },200

Comment: This is my in.csv file, from this file i want to copy 7th column fully into a txt file

Comment: @WalterA out.txt         line1: { "customer": { "name": "abc", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} }
line2: { "customer": { "name": "def", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response has a `,` inside, so field 7 will stop at this point.
When you do not want a real parser you can delete the first 6 and the last field.

Testdata:

```
API,Admin1 ,Admin2 ,Admin3 ,Admin4 ,Admin5 ,Request ,Response_Code,,
v1/customers,200,401,401,401,401,{ "customer": { "name": "abc", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} },200
v1/customers,200,401,401,401,401,{ "customer": { "name": "def", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} },200
v1/customers,200,401,401,401,401,{ "customer": { "name": "g,h", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} },200
```

Command:

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*,){6}//;s/,[^,]*$//' testdata
```

Remark:
The header line has one additinal `,`, so that wil show in incorrect field 7.

Comment: can you please help on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019333/read-a-json-message-from-csv-file-without-removing-any-char-in-shell-script

Comment: Instead of deleting the first 6 and the last field, How to move the first 6 and last field to a another file

Comment: That is another question and you can try it with `awk`. Something like `awk -v out="anotherfile" -F, '{for (i=1;i<7;i++) printf( "%s,", $i) >>out; print $NF >> out}' in.tsv`. You can add something like `(i=7; i<NF;i++)` for "field 7".

Comment: Thank you very much, One more final question -  Is there a way to remove comma from column 1 to column 6 not inside column 7  - v1/customers?customer_id=0,200,401,401,401,401,{ "customer": { "name": "abc", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} } output needed like v1/customers?customer_id=0 200 401 401 401 401 { "customer": { "name": "abc", "email":"mailme2@xxx.com","account_classification": "xyz"} }

Comment: sed 's/,/ /g' this is command to replace comma with space, but i want this should be happen from column 1 to column 6

Comment: sed 's/,/ /6' this is command to add space before 6th column, @Walter can you help me please

Comment: The `awk` given in a previous comment can be changed to print without comma. You must take a look into awk how to check the number om commas in field 7 (about NF-8) and print the parts inside field 7 separated with commas. Place a new question when you get stuck.